# unity3d ios. App doesn't clear threads while running

Tags: ios, unity-game-engine, client-server

Some time ago I had a very strange situation.

I use Unity3d and C# to develop a client-server application for iOs. On an iPad mini retina, after building in Xcode, about 50% of the time (or little more) I have trouble with threads that don't clear after completing. In the profiler I see the number threads my app is using is about 83-85. After this my app doesn't respond at all (and we don't close it). If we close the connection to the server (by shutting down the server) the app starts working again.

In other cases all work good. Thread clear correctly.

To work with the server we use `WWW`:

```
StartCoroutine(MakeRequest(request, command, delaySeconds));

private IEnumerator MakeRequest(string request, Command command, float delaySeconds = 0f)
{
    if (delaySeconds > 0.00001f)
       yield return new WaitForSeconds(delaySeconds);

    WWW requester = new WWW(apiUrl, Recode(Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(request), -1, outgoingKey));

    yield return requester;

    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(requester.error))
    {
       Debug.LogWarning(requester.error);
    }
    else
    {
       //something
    }

    requester.Dispose();
}
```

Do I have any options to fix this?

UPD:

Unity version 4.6.8f1. iOs version - 9.2

Comment: You're not repeatedly calling this, are you? Just making sure.

Comment: @andeart repeatedly - no. Sometimes few times a row.